# Returning optionals from a method

Tags: swift

I have a basic set of constructs, including a `Garage` struct to define a car garage, a `Garages` class to encapsulate a hardcoded list of garages, and a `Car` class that searches the garages based on a manufacturer String.

My issue is that the `Car.findGarageByManufacturer` needs to optionally return a `Garage` instance (returning `nil` if it's not found).` But I'm given the following error:

**Value of optional type "Garage?" not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?**

...on the line `return foundGarage`

How do you return optionals inside of a method?

```
// Using a struct because an 'Object' type doesn't seem to exist :-/
struct Garage {
    var name: String
    var manu: String
}

// Hardcorded set of garages, using class to test returning an array of a struct instance.
class Garages {
    func getGarages() -> Array<Garage> {
        var garages: Garage[] = [
            Garage(name: "VW Car Park", manu: "VW"),
            Garage(name: "Williams BMW", manu: "BMW"),
            Garage(name: "Hadwins", manu: "VW")
        ]
        return garages;
    }
}

// Immediately create an instance of the Garages class
let garages = Garages()

class Car {
    func findGarageByManufacturer(manufacturer: String) -> Garage {
        var foundGarage: Garage? = nil
        for garage in garages.getGarages() {
            if(garage.manu == manufacturer) {
                foundGarage = garage
            }
        }
        // This is the line that's causing an error
        // How do we optionally return a garage?
        return foundGarage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func findGarageByManufacturer(manufacturer: String) -> Garage
```

must be

```
func findGarageByManufacturer(manufacturer: String) -> Garage?
```

(note the question mark)